# Getting from Honolulu to Mauna Kea

Tags: transportation, hawaii, honolulu

I'm lining up a few days in Honolulu next month.  While there are things on that island that I want to see (Pearl Harbour etc), I'd really love to get to Mauna Kea as well.

[Wikitravel's Honololu article](http://wikitravel.org/en/Honolulu) doesn't really explain much about getting to other islands, however.

What's the easiest and cheapest backpacker-style way to change islands.  I assume helicopters are options, but there must be a cheaper way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pearl Harbor might be a little easier to get to when in Honolulu.  There are regularly [scheduled buses that go to Pearl Harbor](http://www.thebus.org/Route/Routes.asp).  The ones you are looking for are [Route 9](http://www.thebus.org/Route/Maps/rm9.pdf), [PH2](http://www.thebus.org/Route/Maps/rm9.pdf), [PH3](http://www.thebus.org/Route/Maps/rm83.pdf), [PH4](http://www.thebus.org/Route/Maps/rm83.pdf), [PH5](http://www.thebus.org/Route/Maps/rm85.pdf).  There is one free transfer with any one way fare and fare for an adult is $2.50 one way.

The best I could find on Mauna Kea is the [organized tour](http://maunakea.com/details.htm) which will run about $200 but you will need to fly from Honolulu to Kona or Hilo on the Big Island to take advantage of it and that will be another $200 plus depending on how few days you are actually in Hawaii it may not even be feasible.

**EDIT**

Found this link talking about [ferry services on the Islands](http://www.bestplaceshawaii.com/tips/big_kahuna/ferries.html)